# Upsell url duplicating

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, url, up-sells

For some peculiar reason the upsell's on my product pages all have the same product url as the first upsell.

We are using Varnish for caching and I have added the esi to the upsell block in local.xml but still the issue persists.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Code:

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
<div class="box-collateral box-up-sell">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('You may also like...') ?></h2>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php $this->resetItemsIterator() ?>
    <?php for($_i=0;$_i<$this->getRowCount();$_i++): ?>
        <?php for($_j=0;$_j<$this->getColumnCount();$_j++): ?>
            <?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()): ?>
            <?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_link->getId()) ?>
            <li class="item first">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(162,162); ?>" width="162" height="162" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                                </a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php $_product->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></a></h2>
                <?php if($_product->getShortDescription()): ?>
                                <div class="short-description">
                                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_product->getShortDescription() ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true, '-upsell') ?>
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: can you provide some code? My psychic sensors are a bit off today :)

Comment: I guess there's nothing to do with Varnish. Most likely there's a problem in you upsells template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's your problem.

```
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_link->getId()) ?>
```

First of all I don't understand why you need to load the product and not use the `$_link` object instead. But I assume you have a reason.
You need to replace that with

```
<?php $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_link->getId()) ?>
```

When using `getSingleton` the same instance of the product model is used each time.
When you call `load` on that the `_data` member of the instance is merged with the values from the database.
When you try to get the product url you end up calling `if ($product->hasUrlDataObject()) ...`. For the first item that expression evaluates to `false` and the url is retrieved correctly. The second time, because it's the same object that is evaluated to `true` and the url is returned based on the existing values. That's why you get the same url.